# Sentence Segmentation and Regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Ok, I know there's a lot of topics about this, and I've read a lot trying to get this to work.  The task is to split a paragraph into separate sentences.  I guess I'm not quite sure how regex works, as I've tried numerous variations, but nothing gives me the result I desire.

```
paragraph = "Mr. Smith bought cheapsite.com for 1.5 million dollars, i.e. he "\
        "paid a lot for it.  Did he mind?  Adams Jones Jr. thinks he "\
        "didn't.  In any case, this isn't true...  Well, with a "\
        "probability of .9 it isn't."

sentenceEnd = re.compile('[.!?][\s]{1,2}(?=[A-Z])')
sentenceList = sentenceEnd.split(paragraph)

for sentence in sentenceList:
        print(sentence)
```

This is the code I've been attempting, and everywhere I look, it seems the [.?!][/s],etc. is what's recommended in re.compile.  However, when I print the paragraph with this code, I just get:

```
OUTPUT:
Mr
Smith bought cheapsite.com for 1.5 million dollars, i.e. he paid a lot for it
Did he mind
Adams Jones Jr. thinks he didn't
In any case, this isn't true..
Well, with a probability of .9 it isn't.
```

What am I missing or not understanding?

Thanks.

Comment: Please write the desired output. It will help us to understand exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You've done very well for not knowing regular expressions beforehand!

Your problem doesn't have as much to do with your code as much as it has to do with simple typographic ambiguity. How should a non-intelligent computer know that `Mr.` is not a sentence, since it technically follows the rule you prescribed? That is, a period followed by one or two spaces followed by an uppercase letter?

The word you may find useful next is *heuristics*. That is, you need a clever *heuristic* for approximating our intelligent way of separating sentences, as humans. This isn't necessarily an easy feat—the first Google result for searching sentence-splitting heuristics is [this presentation involving Markov chains and other fancy schmancy ideas](http://www.nactem.ac.uk/dtc/dtc-Tsuruoka.pdf).

If you want to implement your own heuristic, you can for example exclude the cases where the period is *preceded* by a salutation, *e.g.* `(?<!Mr|Mrs|Ms|Dr)`. I would also recommend putting the period in a zero-width assertion (*i.e.* a lookahead or lookbehind assertion) so that the period's not "eaten up" during the splitting.

---

**Summary of Comments Below**

To filter out salutations as sentence-enders:

```
(?<=(?<!Mr)(?<!Mrs)(?<!Ms)(?<!Dr)(?<!Jr)[.!?])\s{1,2}(?=[A-Z])
```

Here's [an Ideone demo](http://ideone.com/25TUP2).

Comment: That's one of the issues I'm having.  Also, why is the '?' disappearing?  I've tried removing the space requirements and the uppercase letter rules, but it just makes everything worse.

Comment: _All_ your ending punctuations are disappearing—because you're "eating them up." Contrast to this: `(?<=[.!?])[\s]{1,2}(?=[A-Z])`. By putting the punctuation in a zero-width assertion, you prevent them from becoming part of the split.

Comment: To get you started, here's how you'd add to that expression to exclude prefixes: `(?<=(?<!Mr|Mrs|Ms|Dr)[.!?])\s{1,2}(?=[A-Z])`. What that's saying is, _"A space (or two) that is (1) preceded by an ending punctuation which in turn is **not** preceded by one of those salutations, and (2) followed by an uppercase letter."_

Comment: Ok, so ?< refers to look behind?  (I tested and got an error regarding look behind requiring a fixed width pattern.)  I used... nevermind, just saw your previous comment.  Let me play with that.

Comment: Oh, that's a pickle. Yes, in most implementations of regular expressions, a lookbehind assertion must always be of a fixed length (for sake of regex efficiency). The problem here is, I think, the `Mrs`, so a hacky trick would be to do `(?<!.Mr|Mrs|.Ms|.Dr)` instead—that is, force everything to be 3 characters. (By the way, `.` there is a _wildcard_, _not_ a literal period.)

Comment: Ok, so I tried 're.compile('?<=(?<!.Mr|Mrs|.Ms|.Dr)[.!?])/s{1.2}(?=[A-Z)')' and I got an error that says "sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat"

Comment: Typos: You have `{1.2}` instead of `{1,2}`, `/s` instead of `\s`, and forgot to close `[A-Z`.

Comment: Ugh...  I need to pay attention to my typing.  Anyways, I now have `re.compile('?<=(?<!.Mr|Mrs|.Ms|.Dr)[.!?])\s{1,2}(?=[A-Z])')` and return the same error.

Comment: Hm, I just noticed you're also missing a parentheses at the beginning :-)

Comment: D'oh!  Ok.  Got that fixed, too.  Still having Mr. show up on it's own line, but I'll do some more investigation.  Don't want you feeling like you're writing my whole code for me.

Comment: No worries; this is fun for me—you've put in a decent amount of effort and this is honestly not an easy task. Anyway, I just realized that that would happen. The reason is that, at the beginning of the string, there aren't 3 characters, so it technically does _not_ match `.Mr`, which makes it pass the non-salutation check, when we don't want it to. That's a headache because any other way involves breaking the fixed-width rule. I think I have another workaround in mind, one minute...

Comment: Got it. Let's break the inner assertion up into multiple assertions, thereby allowing us to work around the fixed-width rule :-) `(?<=(?<!Mr)(?<!Mrs)(?<!Ms)(?<!Dr)(?<!Jr)[.!?])\s{1,2}(?=[A-Z])` It might be hard to grasp why this works. It works because lookaround assertions are considered to have a width of 0. So previously, the `Mr|Mrs|Ms|Dr` meant that the assertion could be 2 or 3 characters. But now, each separate assertion, `Mr`, `Mrs`, etc. are in itself fixed-width, and then for the _outer_ assertion, all the inner assertions are considered _zero_ width!